# A special neighborhood of a compact set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $U$ is a bounded and connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq2$). Does $\partial{U}$ (boundary of $U$) have an open neighborhood $V$ containing the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus U$ and such that each bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\partial{U}$ contains at least one point of $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus V$?

Comment: $\overline U$ usually denotes the closure of $U$. For the boundary, use $\partial U$ (`\partial U`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $X\subset \Bbb R^2$ be the union of closed discs $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline D\left(\frac 1n,\varepsilon_n\right)$$ where $\varepsilon_n$ is chosen small enough so that the discs don't intersect.

Then $\overline X=X\cup\{(0,0)\}$.

Put $U=\left(\Bbb R^2\setminus \overline X\right)\cap D(0, 1)$. The $\cap D(0, 1)$ is just to make it bounded, but it's not essential.

Now $(0,0)\in \partial U$ (the boundary of $U$), and any open neighbourhood of $\partial U$ must contain $(0,0)$ and therefore infinitely many of the discs $\overline D\left(\frac 1n,\varepsilon_n\right)$.